# Change audio input and output devices from terminal

Tags: terminal, command-line, audio

I'd like to be able to change my audio inputs / outputs from the command line so that I can script my studio setup.

Is it possible to change the selected audio input / output in MacOS from the command line?

Previously, [someone on StackExchange posted a clever AppleScript to do this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/314696/441333). However, I'm specifically looking for a way to do this with a terminal command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did this a while back using a utility.  You muse use HomeBrew to install [switchaudio-osx](https://github.com/deweller/switchaudio-osx).

Someone create a webpage giving instructions how to install and use switch audio-ox.  I don't want to take credit for their work.  Here is the web page:

Here is a summary and usage of the app:

**To Install:**

`brew install switchaudio-osx`

**Usage:**

`SwitchAudioSource -s "name of audio device"`

example: `SwitchAudioSource -s "MacBook Pro Speakers"`

Here is a list of command switches:

```
SwitchAudioSource [-a] [-c] [-f format] [-t type] [-n] -s device_name | -i device_id | -u device_uid

-a : shows all devices  
-c : shows current device  

-f format : output format (cli/human/json). Defaults to human.  
-t type : device type (input/output/system). Defaults to output.  
-n cycles the audio device to the next one  
-i device_id : sets the audio device to the given device by id  
-u device_uid : sets the audio device to the given device by uid or a substring of the uid  
-s device_name : sets the audio device to the given device by name
```

Source: [Switch audio output via command line on MacOS - By Pete Houston](https://blog.petehouston.com/switch-audio-output-via-command-line-on-macos/)