# How to make Mac microphone as default?

Tags: headphones, settings, microphone

When I connect my bluetooth headset, macOS starts to use headset's mic, which is terrible by itself. I am tired of constantly entering settings and changing input source from headset to Mac microphone. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is the  behavior for macOS and it cannot be changed.  It assumes that the new microphone (even if part of a headset) you just connected is the one you intend to use so it switches to it.

There’s no setting you can change, but there is a [utility to somewhat automate the switching back your audio device](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/453656/119271).  Simply create a simple script and put it on your desktop to change the audio back to what you want as your default.

Comment: OH! THERE IS "SHELL WAY"!1!11 Thank you!