# How to remove an audio device on Mac?

Tags: macos

I have about 10 audio devices in the dropdown list, but I only switch between 2. I would like to remove all the HDMI devices. The - button on MIDI setup is greyed out.

Not trying to remove the plugin devices like Zoom or sunflower, and not trying to stop it from auto switching to unwanted devices. I'm on Ventura and I have been searching for this since El Capitan, thought they would have added this feature after all these years.

Comment: Does this help in any way?  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/453656/119271

Comment: Making a script to switch to the only audio devices I use would be helpful, but those HDMI audio devices are still in the menu. If there is absolutely no way to hide them then this would be a solution.